# How can I get a clean copy of the various WebUI config files?

Tags: gui-extensions, configuration, installation

I've been experimenting with the configuration of some GUI extensions, and in the process, I've completely broken the GUI.

If I were a smarter person, then obviously I'd have "init"ted a GIT repository in the WebUI folder before I started, but I didn't, so now I'm looking for a way to compare the virgin installation with what I now have.

I considered making a copy of WebUI and then doing a repair install, but then I'd also have to install the hotfix rollup, and I wondered if there's a lazier way. (A clean install on a separate system would also work, but that's even less lazy.)

Are the original config files available online anywhere? Can I easily extract them from the installer? What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: I guess those files are hiding in the installer somewhere. Afaik there is one clean option, to install from scratch on a clean box, apply the hotfixes and copy the files you need. But even then you make assumptions on which hotfixes are installed on the original machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration files are not available online anywhere that I am aware of.

Technically you *could* extract them from the installer using tools like dark.exe (from Windows Installer XML) to extract the MSI files from the executable and LessMSIerables (to extract the files from the resulting MSI files).

But that would require installing those tools and I'm pretty sure the methods you already mentioned would be easier.